# Only one Rebbi for hashkafa

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy

I was told there is a gemara which stresses the importance of having only one Rebbi for hashkafa as multiple teachers in this area would only result in confusion. Anyone know where this gemara is? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are referring to the following Talmudic passage, though it is not particularly about hashkafa?

**[Avodah Zarah 19a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=19&format=pdf)**

> והיה כעץ שתול על פלגי מים אמרי דבי ר' ינאי כעץ שתול ולא כעץ נטוע כל הלומד תורה מרב אחד אינו רואה סימן ברכה לעולם אמר להו רב חסדא לרבנן בעינא דאימא לכו מלתא ומסתפינא דשבקיתו לי ואזליתו כל הלומד תורה מרב אחד אינו רואה סימן ברכה לעולם שבקוהו ואזול קמיה דרבא אמר להו הני מילי סברא אבל גמרא מרב אחד עדיף כי היכי דלא ליפלוג לישני
>
> And he shall be like a tree transplanted  by streams of water.  — Those of the school of R. Jannai said: 'a tree transplanted,' not 'a tree planted' — [which implies that] whoever learns Torah from one master only will never achieve great success. Said R. Hisda to the Rabbinic students: I have a mind to tell you something, though I fear that you might leave me and go elsewhere: 'Whoever learns Torah from one master only will never achieve great success.'  They did leave him and went [to sit] before Rabbah, who however explained to them that the maxim only applies to lessons in logical deductions, **but as to oral traditions  it is better to learn from one master only, so that one is not confused by the variation in the terms used.**
>
> ([Soncino translation, my emphasis](https://halakhah.com/zarah/zarah_19.html))